# What to download in order to make nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize work?

Tags: python, nltk

I am going to use `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize` on a cluster where my account is very limited by space quota. At home, I downloaded all `nltk` resources by `nltk.download()` but, as I found out, it takes ~2.5GB.

This seems a bit overkill to me. Could you suggest what are the minimal (or almost minimal) dependencies for `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize`? So far, I've seen `nltk.download('punkt')` but I am not sure whether it is sufficient and what is the size. What exactly should I run in order to make it work?

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but you might want to [check out spaCy](https://spacy.io) as an alternative to NLTK.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are right. You need Punkt Tokenizer Models. It has 13 MB and `nltk.download('punkt')` should do the trick.

Comment: Also, if you run `nltk.download()`, the NLTK Downloader should open (a GUI application), so you can browse all packages.

Comment: or use the terminal: `python -m nltk.downloader 'punkt'`. Also note that the 13 MB is the zipped file, the final thing is ~ 36 MB.

Answer (score 14):

**In short**:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

would suffice.

---

**In long**:

You don't necessary need to download all the models and corpora available in NLTk if you're just going to use `NLTK` for tokenization.

Actually, if you're just using `word_tokenize()`, then you won't really need any of the resources from `nltk.download()`. If we look at the code, the default `word_tokenize()` that is basically the [TreebankWordTokenizer](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L67) shouldn't use any additional resources:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data/
chunkers  corpora  grammars  help  models  stemmers  taggers  tokenizers
alvas@ubi:~$ mv nltk_data/ tmp_move_nltk_data/
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
>>> tokenizer.tokenize('This is a sentence.')
['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.']
```

But:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ ls nltk_data/
chunkers  corpora  grammars  help  models  stemmers  taggers  tokenizers
alvas@ubi:~$ mv nltk_data/ tmp_move_nltk_data
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize
>>> sent_tokenize('This is a sentence. This is another.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 90, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 801, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 919, in _open
    return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 641, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/home/alvas/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - u''
**********************************************************************

>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize('This is a sentence.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 106, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 90, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 801, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 919, in _open
    return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 641, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/home/alvas/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - u''
**********************************************************************
```

But it looks like that's not the case, if we look at [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py#L93](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L93). It seems like `word_tokenize` has implicitly called `sent_tokenize()` which requires the `punkt` model.

I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature but it seems like the old idiom might be outdated given the current code:

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> sentences = 'This is a foo bar sentence. This is another sentence.'
>>> tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(sentences)]
>>> tokenized_sents
[['This', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'another', 'sentence', '.']]
```

It can simply be:

```
>>> word_tokenize(sentences)
['This', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.', 'This', 'is', 'another', 'sentence', '.']
```

But we see that the `word_tokenize()` flattens the list of list of string to a single list of string.

---

Alternatively, you can try to use a new tokenizer that was added to NLTK [`toktok.py`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/toktok.py) based on https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok that requires no pre-trained models.

Answer (score 1):

If you have huge NLTK pickles in lambda, the code editor won't be available to edit. Use Lambda layers. You may just upload the NLTK data and include the data in the code like below.

```
nltk.data.path.append("/opt/tmp_nltk")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

EXAMPLE_TEXT = "Hello Mr.Smith,how are you doing today?"

print(sent_tokenize(EXAMPLE_TEXT))
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Nltk.download('punkt') will be enough to solve the problem of tokenizing