# Using a returned for loop variable in main function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, undefined, nltk

I want to use the variable of a for loop in my main function.

This will throw an error saying x is undefined:

```
text = 'rough example'
def splitter(text):
    for x in sent_tokenize(text):
        print(x)
        return x

def main():
    x = splitter(text)

main()
```

Comment: Just tried to execute your code in python 3 -> worked. Which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try adding in the beginning of your code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

It worked for me... (printing "rough example", no error thrown)

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101114/what-to-download-in-order-to-make-nltk-tokenize-word-tokenize-work).